# About Codeanywhere python version

Tags: django, python-3.x, codeanywhere

I have two questions about using Codeanywhere:
First, when I choose Python3 stack, I still see python version 2.7. Do they support 2.7 and 3.4 at the same time?

[image: Python3 stack still showing python 2.7]

Second, if I deploy the django project by "python manage.py runserver" in the SSH terminal, and I copy the IP address from the description, I can't access on 
chrome.

Comment: Generally the command to run Python 3 is `python3`.

Answer (score 0):

If you had install python2 and python3

*use 'python' to run python2 and 'python3' to run python3*

I'm not sure what IP address you copied, if you follow the django tutorial, that will be

```
http://localhost:8000/polls/
```

or

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/polls/
```

[the does here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/intro/tutorial01/)